# .NET Core route based authentication with multiple B2C environments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, azure-ad-b2c

## Situation

We have clients that should be able to login into our application. Our clients do also have clients, who also may login. Therefore we have an Azure AD B2C environment per client.

So, we want to have one single application that can be used to authenticate against multiple Azure B2C environments. We want to have this route-based. So:

/client1 goes to B2C environment Client1B2C, with user flow B2C_1_Client1

/client2 goes to B2C environment Client2B2C, with user flow B2C_1_Client2

## Challenge

So, we need to define multiple instances of AddOpenIdConnect. I do this inside a specific builder, so my Startup.cs keeps clean:

**Startup.cs**

```
            ...
            var AzureAdB2CSettings = new List<AzureAdB2COptions>();
            Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:AzureAdB2C").Bind(AzureAdB2CSettings, c => c.BindNonPublicProperties = true);

            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                ...
            })
            .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options), AzureAdB2CSettings)
            ...
```

And there is the builder:

**AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs**

```
        ...
        public static string policyToUse;
        
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdB2COptions> configureOptions, List<AzureAdB2COptions> openIdOptions)
        {
            ...
            foreach(var b2c in openIdOptions)
            {
                builder.AddOpenIdConnect(b2c.SignUpSignInPolicyId, b2c.SignUpSignInPolicyId, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = b2c.Authority;
                    options.ClientId = b2c.ClientId;
                    options.CallbackPath = b2c.CallbackPath;
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = b2c.SignedOutCallbackPath;
                    options.ClientSecret = b2c.ClientSecret;
                });
            }

            return builder;
        }
        ...

        public Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
        {
            ...
            string policyToUse = "B2C_1_" + context.Request.Query["area"];
            ...

            var b2cSettings = AzureAdB2CSettings.Find(x => x.SignUpSignInPolicyId.ToLower().Equals(policyToUse.ToLower()));

            AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.policyToUse = b2cSettings.DefaultPolicy;
            ...
```

Yippee ya yeeey! We can have a dynamic amount of add AddOpenIdConnect, based on a configuration file. The chosen authentication scheme has been set to the static string "AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtension.policyToUse".

But now it comes... how to define the Authorization header?

**BackofficeController.cs**

```
        ...
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.policyToUse)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ChooseBackoffice()
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
```

AUTCH!! You can't use dynamic attributes... Have tried to set the chosen scheme as a default, but it seems we can only define a default at startup, not during runtime...

Any suggestions how to solve this challenge?

Comment: The roles on the server have to be set properly : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs

Comment: Thank you @jdweng. Aren't these roles usable if you have one B2C tenant, and the users inside have different roles? So are you saying I should use one big B2C tenant for all clients (and clients of the clietns), and the users inside the B2C tenant have different roles to identify which customer it is?

Comment: I do not know your requirements.  You have to determine which role is appropriate for your application.  I'm just telling you the root cause of the authentication failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems indeed impossible at the moment to have multiple B2C environments connected to one Azure App Service.

Therefore there is a choice:

1. Don't do it. Just create one giant B2C environment.
2. Make a multi-instance application instead of a multi-tenant application.

Our partner came with another solution. We haven't explored this route. Who knows does this help somebody:

3. Orchard core. Seems like a multi-tenant .NET Core solution. Looks like a complete application, where this multi-tenant question will be handled.

We did choose option 2. This makes sure we have a good separation of data. There are more hosting costs, although with a multi-tenant application all the traffic does to one application. This does require better hardware, so is also more expensive. I do not know which option is more expensive.

Now comes the question how to deploy this efficiently, but that's another question...

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to set all possible values of `AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.policyToUse` in config and read from there.

For each action method/controller (as per your use case), define the attribute value from these configs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The different "policy's" (wrong term I guess) are already in a config file. In the startup.cs all available "policy's" are read from the appsettings.json. All available options are passed onto the AddAzureAdB2C method, and all are added by looping though each one and using builder.AddOpenIdConnect. The real issue is how to let the program know which openIdconnect to use? I want this route-based, but can't define this in runtime...

Comment: I did a similar thing in last project, we have to give user an option to select their provider company and based on their selection, navigate the user to the company's SISU page.

Comment: Does this help you?

Comment: Sort of. We could make a page to select a provider. Based on that redirect them to a specific SISU page. The real deal is we don't want 1 B2C environment with multiple SISU flows, but we want multiple B2C environments with 1 SISU flow...

Comment: Ohh, that is not possible AFAIK. Each B2C will have different SISU page.